# Having trouble wrapping my head around Generics and Inheritance

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

Im in a bit of entanglement when it comes to generics and inheritance. The overall idea is a builder pattern for a variety of components and group or container components containing other components. Some component groups require a specific component some can be any components. That's where the problem lies. Best explained in code I think:

```
public abstract class AbstractGroupComponentBuilder <T extends ComponentGroup<R>, R extends AbstractDashboardComponent> implements ComponentBuilder<ComponentGroup<R>> {
    private List<ComponentBuilder<R>> children;    
    protected void child(ComponentBuilder<R> builder){
        children.add(builder);
    }
...
}

public  class ComponentGroupBuilder extends AbstractGroupComponentBuilder<ComponentGroup<AbstractDashboardComponent>, AbstractDashboardComponent>{

    public <T> TableBuilder<T> table(Class<T> clazz){
        TableBuilder<T> builder = new TableBuilder<T>(clazz);
        child(builder);  // PROBLEM HERE: The method child(ComponentBuilder<AbstractDashboardComponent>) in the type AbstractGroupComponentBuilder<ComponentGroup<AbstractDashboardComponent>,AbstractDashboardComponent> is not applicable for the arguments (TableBuilder<T>)

    }
    ...   
}

public class TableBuilder<T> implements ComponentBuilder<Table> {
...
}

public class Table extends AbstractDashboardComponent{
...
}

public class ComponentGroup<T extends AbstractDashboardComponent> extends AbstractDashboardComponent {
...
}

public interface ComponentBuilder<T extends AbstractDashboardComponent> {   
    public T build();
}
```

So the error the compiler has is: `"The method child(ComponentBuilder<AbstractDashboardComponent>) in the type AbstractGroupComponentBuilder<ComponentGroup<AbstractDashboardComponent>,AbstractDashboardComponent> is not applicable for the arguments (TableBuilder<T>)"`
How come that is not compatible since `TableBuilder<T> extends ComponentBuilder<Table>` and 'Table extends AbstractDashboardComponent'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, your builder is of type `TableBuilder<Table>`. This is not compatible with `ComponentBuilder<AbstractDashboardComponent>`. The prolbem isnt `ComponentBuilder`, it's the stuff inside the `<>`. Unlike normal types, the stuff in side `<>` is **invariant**, meaning, the types have to match exactly, no subtype allowed.

Here is why: I'm going to use very simple and familiar types to explain it:

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Number> numbers = ints; // PROBLEM LINE
numbers.add(5.0);
ints.get(0); // uhoh - that's a double and not an int!
```

The line marked `PROBLEM`? That won't compile. The fix is this:

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<? extends Number> numbers = ints; // this is fine
numbers.add(5.0); // PROBLEM LINE
ints.get(0); // uhoh - that's a double and not an int!
```

In this example, the error is on the third line: You cannot add *ANYTHING* to a `List<? extends NothingYouTypeHereCanFixThat>` (irrelevant detail: except the literal `null`).

Which is why line 2 is now fine.

You need to do the same thing and throw some `? extends` around until it compiles.

`<T>` = invariant; only precise Ts work out, but you can use T in all ways you'd want.

`<? extends T>` = covariant; T or any subtype of T is fine, but you can only call get-style methods.

`<? super T>` = contravariant; T or any SUPERTYPE of T is fine, but you can only call add-style methods (you can call get, but you'd just get Object).

contravariant rarely comes up. It lets you do:

```
List<? super Integer> list = ...;
list.add(5); // compiles fine.
Object o = list.get(0); // all you get is `Object` here.
```

and if you have a `List<Number>`, you can assign it to the list variable.